# How to connect a laptop with broken screen to an external TV screen?

Tags: boot, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

My screen stopped working one day so I disconnected it. The current condition is like in the pictures below.

I am trying to connect it to an external screen using HDMI. This screen is the TV Screen we have in the house. I have tried the following:

- Trying to switch with the key combinations
- Trying to boot into BIOS
- Trying it with VGA cable instead
- Trying to boot into safe mode(not sure if I succeeded this one)

What else can I try? I have the broken screen separately and I have also tried connecting the broken screen while I try to boot into external screen.

I am not sure if I have been able to go pass the password screen since I don't hear anything from the computer about booting sounds but since I do not have ANY connection to any screen, I think it should straight up boot into the external screen?

Should I try with a windows install cd? Or maybe linux? I am quite lost.

The model and the pictures are below.

This is the only information I could find about the model. It is a company specific to Turkey: http://www.comx.co.za/laptop-specification-sheet.php?laptop=42278

[image]

Comment: Some laptops might only work on the external screen after you bypassed some boot pages; but others would show the boot screen already externally. I don't know for your model, it depends on the graphics card.

Comment: Could the graphics card may had burnt out?

Comment: Anything could be broken, sure. Normally, the boot sequence should make some beeps if it cannot find any working graphics card. Is your audio on and loud enough so you would hear it? If the machine boots onto a non-visible screen, you should also hear the hard disk (and see its LED flickering). Also, try to boot a CD, to see if the CD drive makes noises. That _might_ help isolate the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to duplicate your screen ? I'm sure there's a hotkey on the keyboard

Comment: The computer runs and I can hear the fan and all the lights are as they should be, I do not hear a noise indicating the graphics card problem but this model has two graphics cards, 560m and intel graphics. I was wondering if it was trying to boot with one while that one is broken

Comment: I did try to duplicate but it is same key combination as before